# Why WCF Service cannot run on hosted server?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, wcf, service

I have created a WCF Service on my ASP.NET website. But when I run the website on the hosted server (such as on real domain somedomain.com), the WCF Service cannot run or called by any request from javascript. It can only run on my local host.

This is the configuration in my web.config file; it has only some xml lines in the configuration tag:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Service">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The information in web.config is generated by Visual Studio 2008 when create WCF Service. Service behavior named “ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior” and in the endpoint tag, it also defined. It uses webHttpBiding for client to call the web service.

The Service.svc file has only one line:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/Service.cs" %>
```

Service.cs file in the App_Code folder at the root of my website. The content of Service.cs is below. Because the Service.cs has a too many lines, so I only post some sample of code just let you see the basic constructor of the Service.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Users;

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "IELTSpedia")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service
{
    public Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    public static string defaultPortalAlias = Class1.GetDefaultPortalAlias1();
    public static string testViewPage = "";
    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the available products to provide data for the Kendo Grid
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>All available products</returns>
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public DataSourceResult Read(int skip, int take, IEnumerable<Sort> sort, Filter filter)
    {
        take = skip + take;
        skip = skip + 1;
        return new DataSourceResult();
    }
}
```

Service.cs file has a method “Read” which will return an object to fill up the grid view at the client web page when calling with javascript. The javascript function I have used to call the service is below:

```
read: {
    url: "http://localhost:8698/dotnetnuke_community_06.02.01_install/Service.svc/Read", //specify the URL which data should return the records. This is the Read method of the Products.svc service.
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web service to serialize JSON
    type: "POST" //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for svc
},
parameterMap: function(data, operation) {
    if (operation != "read") {
        // web service method parameters need to be send as JSON. The Create, Update and Destroy methods have a "products" parameter.
        return JSON.stringify({ service: data.models })
    } else {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
}
```

In the javascript; I have called the service via localhost url of my web service.
This url is valid when I run my website on localhost. When I upload my website to a hosted server, I have changed the url to http://somedomain.com/Service.svc/Read
The problem is that the WCF Service can only call on my local host, but cannot call on the hosted server. I have test the service when run the website on localhost; it is successful and the object is return normally but not on hosted server.

Finally, my issue is How to config WCF Service on hosted server in web.config file.

I hope my sample code can give you the clear look at my issue. I am on the edge of my issue and require some help from stackoverflow community. Please help me for this.

Comment: I have change the info inside system.serviceModel tag. You can see on this link: http://ieltspedia.com.nightshade.arvixe.com/system.serviceModel.txt

The service is seem to run very good on localhost, and receive a message "You have created a service." when attack this link "http://localhost:8698/dotnetnuke_community_06.02.01_install/Service.svc" I think the service is successful active. But one more time I got unluck when it is still cannot run on hosted server. I receive a n error message "500 - Internal server error." when run the service on hosted server.

Comment: My hosted server has return an error message when enter the address of service svc file. 

Service.svc file link: http://ieltspedia.com.nightshade.arvixe.com/Service.svc

The error message is: 

`This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.
Parameter name: item`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the WCF service from javascript, it should be RESTful service. Hence try making WCF a RESTful service. Can refer
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: I'm checking on your topic. I will return later. This question is my nightmare, but I will try all things to got this.

Comment: Now I got the solution from your help and many people from around me, people from internet, other post, people from my hosted server, and my friend. I will show the answer for this topic right now. Let me prepare the document first. Thanks for all of you who has concern on my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer for my question. The document bellow only applies for the WCF Service generated by Visual Studio 2008, ASP.NET Webiste using C#.

**Service Name: Service**

The problem most came from the configuration of web.config file. Let’s look clearly on to the configuration of WCF Service in the web.config file.

This is the content of system.serviceModel tag in web.config which generated by Visual Studio 2008 when create WCF Service.

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Service">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, the service tag has attribute name “Service”. The behavior name is “ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior”. In Service Endpoint Tag, there is two attributes “biding” and “contract” has values “webHttpBinding”, “Service”. These settings are automatic apply on web.config file when Visual Studio 2008 generating the WCF Service.

Now, is all setting from Visual Studio 2008 ready for your Web Service to run on hosted server? The answer is **NO**, we must do some more tasks to get the service ready in use. What will we do next is reconstruction the content of system.serviceModel tag.

Because the address attribute in Service Endpoint Tag is blank, so when we enter the address of Service, it view with an error message *“You do not have permission to view this directory…”*. The server has no knowledge on the address of service, so when client enter the physical address of service, it won’t allow any access.

**1. Set up address for service**

By set up the address for the address of service, I will put some more tags. 
First of all, I will add the address of my website service into the address attribute of endpoint tag:

```
<endpoint address="http://mydomainname.com/Service.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service" />
```

I also add the address of service into serviceHostingEnvironment tag:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
          <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
              <add prefix="http://mydomainname.com"/>
          </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

*Note: The address is only the basic domain-name inside the prefix of “add” tag inside "baseAddressPrefixFilters" tag.*

OK, now it is alright for the address of service. I will move next to the Service Behavior. There is only behavior for endpoint, but not for the service. I will need to add a behavior for service.

**2. Set up behavior for service**

Inside behavior tag I will add the service behavior which named “MyServiceTypeBehaviors”:

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Now, I have behavior name for my service “MyServiceTypeBehaviors” and add it to the attribute “behaviorConfiguration” of service tag inside services:

```
<service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="http://mydomainname.com/Service.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service" />
      </service>
```

**3. Review the structure of "system.serviceModel" tag**

Finally, the configuration of WCF Service is ready for running on a hosted server. Let’s look again the content of system.serviceModel tag in web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
          <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
              <add prefix="http://mydomainname.com"/>
          </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="http://mydomainname.com/Service.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

When we enter the address of service from hosted server, if it show a message *“You have created a service.”* Then our task is done and the service is ready for use. If not we will look again the address of service, are they correct or some behavior names are not correct etc… But I’m sure we will finally find out the problem and solve it with our own hand.
I will delete the entire hyperlink which contain my example code files and change the domain name of my real website for the safe of my website.

I hope my issue can help anyone out there who has the same problem on my issue.

I am kinda thanks for the stackoverflow community and anyone who help me out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an add-on to @tri-nguyen-dung's last comment, which I used to get my service working in a virtual directory on a hosted server (arvixe).

Here's my version of his Web.config section, that is sitting inside `\wwwroot\<virtualdirectory>\Web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="<virtualdirectory>Behaviour" >
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="<virtualdirectory>Behaviour">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0">
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="http://<yourserver>.com"/>
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>             
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
        <service name="<virtualdirectory>.Services.<virtualdirectory>Service" behaviorConfiguration="<virtualdirectory>Behaviour">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://<yourserver>.com"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="http://<yourserver>.com/<virtualdirectory>/Services/<virtualdirectory>Service.svc"
                    behaviorConfiguration="EDGEBehaviour"
                    binding="webHttpBinding"
                    contract="virtualdirectory.Services.I<virtualdirectory>Service" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

With `<yourserver>` and `<virtualdirectory>` being your app address; to get your e.g. service help page my address was `http://<yourserver>.com/<virtualdirectory>/Services/<virtualdirectory>Service.svc/help`. You don't have to use my naming convention for your app code, but it worked for me.

Here's my `I<virtualdirectory>Service.cs` code:

```
namespace <virtualdirectory>.Services
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface I<virtualdirectory>Service
    {
        [OperationContract]
        object GetFormResult(string form_id);
```

Here's the implementation (`<virtualdirectory>Service.svc.cs`):

```
namespace <virtualdirectory>.Services
{
    using <lots>;

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class <virtualdirectory>Service : I<virtualdirectory>Service 
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetFormResult?form_id={form_id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public object GetFormResult(string form_id)
        {
```

Implementation markup (`<virtualdirectory>Service.svc`):

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="<virtualdirectory>.Services.<virtualdirectory>Service" Factory="<virtualdirectory>.WebServiceHostFactory3WithJsonP" CodeBehind="<virtualdirectory>Service.svc.cs" %>
```

Note that I got `WebServiceHostFactory3WithJsonP` from google somewhere, to serve REST+JSON over WCF. The newer WebAPI stuff in .NET 4.5 is better, but my site is in .NET4.

For completeness, here's my javascript that is calling this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery('#formdetails').submit(function () {
    jQuery('.widget_formdetails input[type="submit"]').hide();
    jQuery('.formloading').show();
    var form_parameters = jQuery(this).serialize();
    var form_type = jQuery('#form_type').val();
    switch (form_type) {
        case '<someoption>':
        var js<someoption> = new f<someoption>(  // object helper function
                    jQuery('#textfield1').val(), 
                    jQuery('#textfield2').val(), 
                    jQuery('#textfield3').val()
                    );
        var json<someoption> = JSON.stringify({ Message: js<someoption>});
        $.getJSON(
            '/<virtualdirectory>/Services/<<virtualdirectory>Service.svc/GetFormResult',
            'form_request=' + json<someoption>,
            form_request // callback function
        );
        break;
```